# Phonegap - JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a phonegap app.. in Android 4.0.

This bug appears after a few touch when i'm navigating the app...

```
03-19 01:10:59.052: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x24d00216) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.072: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x2360021e) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.092: D/DroidGap(30016): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
03-19 01:10:59.122: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x20800226) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.122: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x1ec00246) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x24e00216) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x29500212) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x1eb0024a) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x1eb0024e) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI WARNING: DeleteLocalRef(0x1ea00252) failed to find entry
03-19 01:10:59.132: E/dalvikvm(30016): JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016): JNI local reference table (0xc34ff8) dump:
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):   Last 10 entries (of 512):
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       511: 0x410a8aa8 android.content.res.AssetManager
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       510: 0x424a3a10 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       509: 0x4249b9f8 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       508: 0x424939e0 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       507: 0x4248b9c8 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       506: 0x424839b0 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       505: 0x4247b998 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       504: 0x42473980 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       503: 0x4246b968 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       502: 0x42463950 byte[] (32768 elements)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):   Summary:
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):         1 of java.lang.Class
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):       510 of byte[] (32768 elements) (510 unique instances)
03-19 01:10:59.132: W/dalvikvm(30016):         1 of android.content.res.AssetManager
03-19 01:10:59.132: E/dalvikvm(30016): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016): "Thread-1410" prio=5 tid=16 RUNNABLE
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x410f0e90 self=0x3fd428
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016):   | sysTid=30037 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=5161056
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016):   | schedstat=( 935121000 243214000 986 ) utm=72 stm=21 core=0
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:35)
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016):   at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:573)
03-19 01:10:59.132: I/dalvikvm(30016):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-19 01:10:59.132: E/dalvikvm(30016): VM aborting
03-19 01:10:59.132: A/libc(30016): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

Please.. help me with this error!!

Answer (score 1):

I found the Solution to this error. Move your resources (images, fonts,..) from your asset forlder to sdcard folder and te error is fixed !